# Maximum for array of structs with hash in struct member

Tags: ruby

Is there any another way that iterate over and put data in temp array to get pairs for id and maximum value in this data structure:

```
Results_struct = Struct.new(:comp_class, :usage, :competitors)
Competitor_struct = Struct.new(:name, :id, :user_id, :gear, :run,
                           :run_points, :strike, :strike_points,
                           :total)

advanced_comps = Results_struct.new(:advanced, true, [])
intermediate_comps = Results_struct.new(:intermediate, true, [])

comp_el1 = Competitor_struct.new('John D.', '1', '1', nil, [], nil, [], nil, [], nil, nil)
comp_el1.run << {:id => '10', :result => 50, :points => 0}
comp_el1.run << {:id => '11', :result => 100, :points => 0}

comp_el2 = Competitor_struct.new('Jake F.', '2', '2', nil, [], nil, [], nil, [], nil, nil)
comp_el2.run << {:id => '10', :result => 70, :points => 0}
comp_el2.run << {:id => '11', :result => 70, :points => 0}

advanced_comps.competitors << comp_el1
advanced_comps.competitors << comp_el2

# Some other actions
```

I'd like to get

```
[{:id => '10', :result => 70}, {:id => '11', :result => 100}]
```

I had looked on `map` and `select` but did't find way to use it for this purpose.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to convert `Array of structs...` into valid Ruby code.  When you say you want to get a particular array as output, presumably that is for a given argument (`[[1,0],[0,1]]`?). Please clarify that as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've edited question. And also this morning I've found way to do that - just query db for max(result), group('rounds.id'). I'm really sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy, you just need to loop each run of each competitor.

My suggestion is to temporary transform your data structure during the loop, for easy manipulation: an hash where each entry is the id and the content the result.

```
result=advanced_comps.competitors.inject({}) do |elem,comp|
  comp.run.each do |run| 
     elem[run[:id]]=[elem[run[:id]].to_f,run[:result]].max
  end elem
end
```

so result will contains something like this:

```
=> {"10"=>70, "11"=>100.0}
```

Then if you just want to go back to your initial struct:

```
result.map{|k,v|{:id=>k,:result=>v}}

=> [{:id=>"10", :result=>70}, {:id=>"11", :result=>100.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I'll take a stab at it.

Let's first define a `Struct` object:

```
MyClass = Struct.new :id, :result
  #=> MyClass
```

We have:

```
MyClass.class
  #=> Class
MyClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:id, :id=, :result, :result=]
my_class = MyClass.new(1,2)
my_class.id
  #=> 1
my_class.result
  #=> 2
my_class.id = "cat"
  #=> "cat"
my_class.id
  #=> "cat"
```

All we've done so far is create a class with accessors for two instance variables and a simple `initialize` method, exactly the the same as:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :id, :result
  def initialize(id, result)
    @id = id
    @result = result
  end
end

MyClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:id, :id=, :result, :result=]
```

At this point we can forget about how we created this class. We can now reopen it and add methods to improve its functionality.

Let's add the instance method `hash` to create a hash from the values of the two instance variables:

```
class MyClass
  def hash
    { :id => @id, :result => @result }
  end
end

MyClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:id, :id=, :result, :result=, :hash]
```

We could alternatively have done this when creating the class `MyClass`, by using the form of [Struct::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Struct.html#method-c-new) that takes a block:

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:id, :result) do
   def hash
    { :id => @id, :result => @result }
  end
end

MyClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:id, :id=, :result, :result=, :hash]
```

We can now create an array containing hashes associated with instances of the class `MyClass`:

```
a = [[MyClass.new('10', 100).hash, MyClass.new('20', 10).hash],
     [MyClass.new('10', 200).hash, MyClass.new('20',  5).hash]]
  #=> [[{:id=>"10", :result=>100}, {:id=>"20", :result=>10}],
  #    [{:id=>"10", :result=>200}, {:id=>"20", :result=>5}]]
```

I don't understand what you mean by wanting to get the maximum value in the data structure, but once you have the array `a` it should be easy to extract whatever you want. For example, you can extract elements from this array in the usual way:

```
[a[1][0], a[0][1]]
  #=> [{:id=>"10", :result=>200}, {:id=>"20", :result=>10}]
```

Similarly, if, for each element of `a`, you wanted the hash with the largest value for the key `:result`, you could do this:

```
a.map { |b| b.max_by { |h| h[:result] } }
  #=> [{:id=>"10", :result=>100}, {:id=>"10", :result=>200}]
```

Please let me know if this does not answer your question.